# Class not found on 'use' php clause

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I'm trying to deploy a php api that uses your library on a Debian server.

I did the php, composer and library installation but i get a

" Error: Class 'Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac\Sha256' not found in /app/app/controllers/AuthController.php " as if the use clause wasn't looking at the right repository.

My project is as follows :

- /home/$user/api-v3/api/www/vendor/lcobucci/jwt
- /home/$user/api-v3/api/www/app/controllers/AuthController.php

With those imports in the AuthController.php class :

```
use Lcobucci\JWT\Builder;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac\Sha256;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Parser;
use Lcobucci\JWT\ValidationData;
```

Do i have to do something with the autoloader so it seeks your classes in the right directory ?

I do have the require in in my composer.json

```
    "require": {
        "lcobucci/jwt": "^3.2",
}
```

My autoloader.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit284b1942c0e74e39634354f520984117::getLoader();
```

My autoloader_real.php

```
class ComposerAutoloaderInit284b1942c0e74e39634354f520984117
{
    private static $loader;

    public static function loadClassLoader($class)
    {
        if ('Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' === $class) {
            require __DIR__ . '/ClassLoader.php';
        }
    }

    public static function getLoader()
    {
        if (null !== self::$loader) {
            return self::$loader;
        }

        spl_autoload_register(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit284b1942c0e74e39634354f520984117', 'loadClassLoader'), true, true);
        self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
        spl_autoload_unregister(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit284b1942c0e74e39634354f520984117', 'loadClassLoader'));

        $useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION') && (!function_exists('zend_loader_file_encoded') || !zend_loader_file_encoded());
        if ($useStaticLoader) {
            require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload_static.php';

            call_user_func(\Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit284b1942c0e74e39634354f520984117::getInitializer($loader));
        } else {
            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_namespaces.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->set($namespace, $path);
            }

            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_psr4.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->setPsr4($namespace, $path);
            }

            $classMap = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php';
            if ($classMap) {
                $loader->addClassMap($classMap);
            }
        }

        $loader->register(true);

        if ($useStaticLoader) {
            $includeFiles = Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit284b1942c0e74e39634354f520984117::$files;
        } else {
            $includeFiles = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_files.php';
        }
        foreach ($includeFiles as $fileIdentifier => $file) {
            composerRequire284b1942c0e74e39634354f520984117($fileIdentifier, $file);
        }

        return $loader;
    }
}

function composerRequire284b1942c0e74e39634354f520984117($fileIdentifier, $file)
{
    if (empty($GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier])) {
        require $file;

        $GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier] = true;
    }
}
```

My autoload_namespaces.php

```
    <?php

// autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Twig_' => array($vendorDir . '/twig/twig/lib'),
    'Pimple' => array($vendorDir . '/pimple/pimple/src'),
    'Doctrine\\DBAL\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/dbal/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Lexer\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/lexer/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Inflector\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/inflector/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/collections/lib'),
);
```

Comment: Did you called `composer install` or `composer update` after adding this dependency to `composer.json`?

Comment: @rob006 yes, but it only updated phpmailer and phalcon

Answer (score 0):

Using require_once __ DIR __ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php'; in AuthController worked but not require_once '/home/$user/api-v3/api/conf/vendor/autoload.php';